# error trying to query firestore documents using dart

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query Firestore for a certain record where the field that is a List contains two specific elements (order doesn't matter).

However, the error says that I cannot return the value from this query.  Specifically the getter 'documents' is not available for a map.  Ironically, I created the map because the I needed to return a list which is not a Snapshot.

This is my code:

```dart
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    Future<List<ChatsRecord>> getChatDoc(   DocumentReference chatUserRef, DocumentReference authUserRef, ) async {   // Add your function code here!
    
      final firestore =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance; // Get a reference to the Firestore database   final collectionRef =
          firestore.collection('chats'); // Get a reference to the collection   final filteredDocuments = collectionRef.where('users', isEqualTo: [
        authUserRef,
        chatUserRef   ]); // Use the `where` method to filter the list of documents
    
      final queryDocuments = await filteredDocuments
          .get(); // You can then use the get method on this Query object to retrieve the list of documents.
    
      List<ChatsRecord> listChatDocs = [];
    
      for (DocumentSnapshot doc in queryDocuments.documents) {
        ChatsRecord chatDoc = ChatsRecord.fromMap(doc.data);
        listChatDocs.add(chatDoc); // add chatDoc
    
      }
    
      return listChatDocs; }
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: Command failed: flutter build web  --web-renderer html --no-pub --no-version-check
Target dart2js failed: Exception:
lib/custom_code/actions/get_chat_doc.dart:34:39:
Error: Member not found: 'ChatsRecord.fromMap'.
    ChatsRecord chatDoc = ChatsRecord.fromMap(doc.data);
                                      ^^^^^^^
lib/custom_code/actions/get_chat_doc.dart:33:47:
Error: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
 - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' ('/root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-4.2.0/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  for (DocumentSnapshot doc in queryDocuments.documents) {
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Comment: Okay let me check.

Comment: Going forward, I recommend searching for any error message you get as this has been covered before: https://www.google.com/search?q=The+getter+%27documents%27+isn%27t+defined+for+the+class+QuerySnapshot+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

I think is `queryDocuments.docs` not `queryDocuments.documents`

Comment: Let me try. I hope that works. I think I got that as the getter from chatGPT

Comment: That fixed the getter error but I get a member not found:

Error: Member not found: 'ChatsRecord.fromMap'.
    ChatsRecord chatDoc = ChatsRecord.fromMap(doc.data);
                                      ^^^^^^^

Comment: What IDE are you using? I feel like you missing plugin for developing flutter, These kinds of error should appear when coding, Not when compiling.

Comment: And It's doc.data() see this API https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html

Comment: Yeah I am using an embedded IDE, it does sometimes show up in the IDE before compilation but sometimes it doesn't.  Yeah I use ChatGPT to generate some of it.  So ChatsRecord.fromMap.doc.data()?

Comment: It's ChatsRecord.fromMap(doc.data());

Comment: From reading it looks like this will give me a list of snapshot but mapped to fields. So I cannot access the entire doc just the document reference?

Comment: I get the following error:

Error: Member not found: 'ChatsRecord.fromMap'.
    final chatDoc = ChatsRecord.fromMap(doc.data());
                                ^^^^^^^